# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg error

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, iframe, html5-audio

All I'm trying to do is autoplay this audio file. I had to find the solution for doing that in the first place because it wasn't working normally in Chrome and now I'm getting this error and the audio does not play either: 
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg:`
This is my HTML:

```
<iframe src="Assets/silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display: none"></iframe>

<audio id="player" autoplay loop>
     <source src="Assets/bdaysong.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```